# Tag synonym suggestion for planetary-science

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I do not quite understand why we need the tag [planetary-science](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary-science) since we have [planet](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet) as widely used tag. To be quantitative: It is 37 agains 607 (as of February 11, 2021).

If we could all agree on that tags being synonomously used, could somebody with the appropriate rights define the synonym, please?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, [planetary-science](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary-science) covers a topic space that is not applicable to all [planet](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet) questions, so I don't think a synonym is appropriate. [planetary-science](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary-science) was originally conceived to capture questions about atmospheric or geological properties of planets, rather than purely astronomical observations. I see that the term "planetary science" may have broadened since we created the tag--or perhaps we were unaware of the broader use when we conceived it.

In any case, I could see justification for renaming it to better capture the subject area, but I don't think it would be helpful to just blob all of the subject matter together into the massive [planet](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet) tag. Tags are supposed to help us find information about certain subjects easier, and the topic of [planet](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet) in general is so broad it is not very helpful in categorizing alone.